# Question on using Fubini iteratively

Tags: integration, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$ be a measurable function, $\mu$ and $\lambda$ two $\sigma$-finite measures on spaces $X$ and $Y$ respectively.
Then if it holds that
$$
\int_X \int_Y |f(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)| \mu(\mathrm{d}x_1) \lambda(\mathrm{d}y_1)<\infty
$$
then $g(x_1, y_1) = f(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$ is integrable with respect to $\mu \otimes \lambda$ where $x_2$ and $y_2$ are fixed. If also $h(x_2, y_2) = f(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$ is integrable with respect to $\mu \otimes \lambda$ when $x_1$ and $y_1$ are fixed, does it then hold that
$$
\int_{X \times Y}
\int_{X \times Y}
|f(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)|
\mu \otimes \lambda(\mathrm{d}(x_1,y_1))
\mu \otimes \lambda(\mathrm{d}(x_1,y_1))
<
\infty
$$
i.e. $f$ is integrable with respect to $(\mu \otimes \lambda (x_1, y_1)) \otimes (\mu \otimes \lambda (x_2, y_2))$?

Comment: Isn't this a slightly dressed up version of the simpler question: If $\int_X |f(x,y)|\,\mu(dx) < \infty$ for $\lambda$-a.e. $y$, and if $\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\lambda(dy)<\infty$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x$, then $\int_{X\times Y}|f(x,y)|\,(\mu\otimes\lambda)(d(x,y))<\infty$? The answer is "no" because for example $f(i,j) = \delta_{i,j}$ and $\mu= \lambda$ is counting measure on $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.

Comment: In fact I think the question you ask is a special case of substituting appropriate measure spaces and measures for $X$, $Y$, $\mu$ and $\lambda$ in my comment. Take $\mu = \mu'\otimes\lambda'$ and $\lambda = \mu$. Take $X = X'\times Y'$ and $Y = X$. (The primed versions are as in your post.)